# Redirect incorrect SEO URLs to the correct ones

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I currently use the following rules to redirect from standard URLs to SEO URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^books/v/([0-9]+)/(.*)/page([0-9]+) books.php?type=book&id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^books/c/([0-9]+)/(.*)/page([0-9]+) books.php?type=category&id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^books/v/([0-9]+)/(.*) books.php?type=book&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^books/c/([0-9]+)/(.*) books.php?type=category&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^books books.php [L]`
```

Now, what I'd like to do is automatically redirect URLs with correct IDs and wrong titles, to the correct URL.

Stackoverflow does a similar thing - if you enter a URL of a question with a correct ID but a wrong matching title, it will automatically redirect you to the correct URL.

I guess it should be done using PHP, but I don't really know what's the *best* way to do the redirect.

Comment: Put a script call into your `index.php` file that first checks an index against a value and corrects with `header()` and `die()`. This will have little overhead if it's run *before* any of the other content is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is the way to do a redirect like this.

The basic idea is simple:

- Call PHP script with ID and title portions as you show above
- Inside the PHP script, load the record with the ID from the database
- Match title of the record in the database, and the title in the URL.
- If they don't match, do a header redirect to the correct URL with the ID, and the title from the database:

  ```
  header("Location: /books/v/123456");
  die();
  ```

Comment: The best way would be to optimize the initial query lookup on the numeric id, but only if it proves interminably slow.

Comment: @Jared yeah, fair enough, that is a good idea if performance is an issue - but arguably, this should happen rarely enough so a non-optimized approach might be okay.

Comment: I was actually agreeing with *this* answer, but you've edited out the statement I was responding to. I think you meant that `.htaccess` couldn't do it explicitly, right? (Something I also initially thought the OP was asking.)

Comment: @Jared ah, I see! Yes, PHP is the only way to do this. This exceeds .htaccess' capabilities. That was what I was saying there